# Dotnet core 2.0 sonarqube analysis failed

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, .net-core, sonarqube-scan

I use TFS (2017.2) on premise and SonarQube 6.7.1 LTS and SonarC# runner 6.8 (latest), I designed a build definiton that build a dotnet core 2.0 project. SonarQube analysis should be used as:

- Prepare analysis on SonarQube step
- Dotnet build step
- Run code analysis

The problem is that I have no analysis in SonarQube portal.
Files are listed, I can see code but I have no analysis.
I have read some post about it and someone said to use standalone scanner.

Does someone successfully have analyzed dotnet core code with SonarQube through TFS?

Comment: Did you use the VSTS/TFS [extension](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used the the "Integrate with MSBuild" instead of the "Use standalone scanner" but I choose the ".sln" folder and not the ".csproj" folder and now it's ok.

Thanks.